# .htaccess css and image files redirection

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to make it so if `/css` or `/images` path is requested... it redirects to the `/images` directory from the `root` but for all others I want it to direct to the `pages` directory.

I got the second part working... this redirect all to the pages directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pages/
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/$1 [L]
```

but I can't get the first part to work where if the user requests `/css` or `/images` it goes to the default folder rather than having `/pages` in the path.

My folder structure:

```
css
    css files
images
    image files
pages
    index.php
    about
        index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a RewriteCondition to prevent that

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|png|gif|jpg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pages/
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/css" [OR]  # if user access "/css" path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/images"    # or "/images" path
RewriteRule (.*) "/images/$1" [L]        # then redirect to "/images"

RewriteRule (.*) "/pages/$1" [L]         # otherwise redirect to "/pages"
```